# Pdf on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

How to show PDF file with `UIWebView` horizontal with paging scroll PDF.
I can show PDF with `UIWebView` but can not show horizontal with pagination.
I searched but did not resolve.

Answer (score 3):

`UIWebView` does not support pagination for PDF files, you'll have to implement such control on your own or use one of third-party solutions like [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com).